# NetBeans 6.8 crash randomly when pressed Enter?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, crash, netbeans

On my Ubuntu 9.10 I have NetBeans 6.8 running. Now when I press the Enter key (to confirm a dialog box, return a line, etc) in some cases it just crashes. The application just quits unexpectedly. Here's what I got when I executed it from command line:

```
bruce@lee:~$ /usr/local/netbeans-6.8/bin/netbeans
The program '<unknown>' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 416740 error_code 3 request_code 20 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Start it from a terminal and watchout for error messages.

Comment: If I type 'locate netbeans' on the command line I get loads of matches... where is the program (typically) located?

Comment: I'm not in front a Linux PC right now, but try typing "netbe" and hit tab in the terminal. Or check where the menu shortcut leads.

Comment: 'netbe'<tab> doesn't do anything, but found the shortcut

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

Presumably found the solution: Netbeans was starting on openJDK, not the JDK from Sun. Edited the netbeans.conf file to match Sun's JDK.